# Chudnovsky algorithm produces -nan

Tags: c, math, precision, pi, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to implement the [Chudnovsky algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm) for calculating pi.

Here is my implementation:

```
int fact(int n)
{
    if(n<=1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fact(n-1)*n;
}

double calcPi(long n)
{
    double z=0;
    for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        z+=(pow(-1, k)*fact(6*k)*(13591409 + 545140134.0*k))/(fact(3*k)*pow(fact(k), 3)*pow(640320.0, 3.0*k+3.0/2));
    }
    z*=12;
    return 1/z;
}
```

I'm running into a tiny error though. When I plug in values of N that are greater than 12, I get -nan. I'm guessing this has to do with limited precision, some sort of integer overflow, or my absolutely terrible factorial implementation (yes, I was lazy and used recursion. It's 2am).

Anyways, if you've been through this before and can suggest a quick fix, that would be nice.

Maybe I should just use Python, and stop worrying about the overflows.

Happy (almost) New Years!

Comment: why ? python just got infinite space for infinite numbers ? your problem is likely to be shared among all the most common languages and beyond.

Comment: `14!` (or close to that) overflows a 32bit int. `fact(6*k)` is going to overflow really fast.

Comment: @user1824407 "why ? python just got infinite space for infinite numbers ?" - now who the heck is talking about Python? This is C and it's not even close the Python by any means...

Comment: If you used `unsigned long long` everywhere, you could indeed go further, but you'll need to optimize your algo a bit in order to get access to a significantly wider range of valid input values.

Comment: @H2CO3 read the last lines from the OP question ...

Comment: @user1824407 sorry, it was my impression that python automatically implemented a higher floating point precision than C (someone told me this a while ago). I should have fact-checked that.

Comment: @JacobSharf yes and no, as you can see from my answer it's possible with external libs, the usual float type is IEEE 754 compliant and in general it's relatively small for what you want to do. Python offers similar libraries as well as https://www.google.com/#q=python+arbitrary+precision+floating+point+arithmetics+library

Comment: What precision do python floats use? (as in, IEEE 754 single precision? double? triple? Or more specifically how many bits are used in the fraction and exponent components?)

Comment: @JacobSharf since python it's an interpreted language it relies on a piece of software called interpreter, the standard implementation of the python interpreter it's called Cpython, it's basically the python intepreter that comes with your linux distribution or python installer. You can find details about cpython on the official wiki http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html . When talking about this in python you need to have an implementation of reference for the interpreter, if you are not using Cpython refer to the wiki for your interpreter of choice.

Comment: alright, thanks for the info. Will read up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

floating point arithmetics it's not trivial and considering your problem i prefer to answer your question with some tip.

You can solve this with a library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) or [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) , and this is [a good FAQ for both](http://www.mpfr.org/faq.html#mpfr_vs_mpf).

If you really want to master this, on almost every major programming language, you should absolutely start from reading the IEEE 754.

Comment: yes, I've read IEEE 754 many times (it was on my first midterm this quarter). It was just 2am (now 3am) and I wasn't thinking correctly. My guess is that the main problem is an overflow with the factorial function, and not floating point precision issues. Either way, the solution is to implement GMP or MPFR.